# Why are controls called Views in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, view, xamarin.forms

I am curious as to the naming convention.  Why would a button be called a view?  Is this because the individual platforms call their controls like Buttons views?  It is confusing.

edit:  Here is an example, https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/controls/views/

Answer (score 4):

It is because many of the visual elements inherit from the View object and this is named because Xamarin Forms focuses on the MVVM pattern. These controls are considered views to the model you bind to them.  Hope that helps!

Edit: Link for reference to the MVVM focus: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_bindings_to_mvvm/